# Add text to CALayer

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to add a `UILabel` to a `CALayer` without subclassing and drawing it in `drawInContext:`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't think you can add a UIView subclass to a CALayer object. However if you want to draw text on a CALayer object, it can be done using the drawing functions provided in NSString UIKit [additions](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) as shown below. While my code is done in the delegate's drawLayer:inContext method, the same can be used in subclass' drawInContext: method. Is there any specific UILabel functionality that you want to leverage?

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor darkTextColor] CGColor]);

  UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
  /*[word drawInRect:layer.bounds 
          withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:32] 
     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
         alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];*/

  [word drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(30.0f, 30.0f) 
           forWidth:200.0f 
           withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32] 
      lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip];

  UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Comment: [[UIColor darkTextColor] set] also works when the graphics context has been pushed

Comment: @Deepak Danduprolu This work for me, but I wander why should call push and pop function to make it work

Answer (score 154):

```
CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[label setFontSize:20];  
[label setFrame:validFrame];
[label setString:@"Hello"];
[label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[label setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[layer addSublayer:label];

[label release];
```

Comment: IMHO, this is a simpler solution than a custom CALayer or layer delegate as long as you don't need more than basic text drawing. CATextLayer already knows how to draw text, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Mshah2 why the text is comming with non-antialiasing effect? the text is looking like its been magnified

Comment: You need to adjust the content scale of the CALayer otherwise you'll get a blurry text on retina (@2x) or @3x devices. Use: label.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

Comment: As usual the most useful answer at the bottom. Thanks StackOverflow!

Comment: @bicycle, come on man, if it wasn't for Stack Overflow we'd all be without a job

Answer (score 12):

Just to document my approach, I did it like this in Swift 4+ :

```
let textlayer = CATextLayer()

textlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 18)
textlayer.fontSize = 12
textlayer.alignmentMode = .center
textlayer.string = stringValue
textlayer.isWrapped = true
textlayer.truncationMode = .end
textlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
textlayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

caLayer.addSublayer(textlayer) // caLayer is and instance of parent CALayer
```

Answer (score 5):

Your UILabel already has a CALayer behind it.  If you are putting together several CALayers, you can just add the UILabel's layer as a sublayer of one of those (by using its `layer` property).

If it's direct text drawing in a layer that you want, the UIKit NSString additions that Deepak points to are the way to go.  For an example of this in action, the [Core Plot framework](https://github.com/core-plot) has a Mac / iPhone platform-independent CALayer subclass which does text rendering, [CPTextLayer](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/framework/Source/CPTTextLayer.h).

Comment: Hey Brad, I actually used to use this technique, (adding a UILabel's layer to a CALayer) and it seems that maybe it's stopped working in the iOS 8 base SDK? I've started rebuilding an old app I created that exports videos, and the sublayers of the parent CALayer seem to stay nil with this old code. Could be something else wrong, going to keep looking.

Comment: Fixed it. For anyone else who comes along looking for how to make this work compiled against iOS 8 Base SDK, call [label.layer display] before adding the label's layer to another CALayer. Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171790/is-it-safe-to-add-a-stolen-uilabels-layer-to-some-other-calayers-sublayer

Answer (score 3):

Add a CATextLayer as a sublayer and set the string property. That would be easiest and you can easily use a layout manager to make it very generic.

Comment: ... _can easily use a layout manager_...  
  
Well, in MacOS, yes, but not in iOS. CALayers in iOS don't support layout managers: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layout.html

Answer (score 1):

The answers below are fine, just make sure you add otherwise you text will be blurry:

```
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Final code for Swift:

```
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 15)
textLayer.fontSize = 12
textLayer.string = "my text"
textLayer.foregroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyCALayer: CALayer {

    ......

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx)
        let text = "這是一段普通的文字"
        let textAttrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
        var drawPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        for char in text {
            let word = NSAttributedString(string: String(char),
                                          attributes: textAttrs)
            let wordBounds = word.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: .max, height: .max), context: nil)
            word.draw(at: drawPoint)
            drawPoint = CGPoint(x: drawPoint.x + wordBounds.width, y: drawPoint.y)
        
            let whitespace = NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: textAttrs)
            let whitespaceBounds = whitespace.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: .max, height: .max), context: nil)
            whitespace.draw(at: drawPoint)
            drawPoint = CGPoint(x: drawPoint.x + whitespaceBounds.width, y: drawPoint.y)
        }
    
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }

    ......
}
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Always remember to remove previous sublayers, if you gonna add another one, to prevent duplicating views:

```
if let sublayers = layer.sublayers {
    for sublayer in sublayers {
        sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
}
```