# Issues in save pdf file on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I have a pdf file in my iPad application. I want to save that pdf file on iPad so that I can read it out of my application. I am using  the following path for save pdf file on iPad:-

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

 NSString *fileBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.pdf"];
```

But I am not able to find this pdf file on my iPad.
Can anyone suggest me how can I find it ?
Is file path wrong? then suggest me the file path for saving the pdf file ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

1) See this [SO question/answer regarding creation of a pdf from a UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454309/get-a-pdf-png-as-output-from-a-uiwebview-or-uiview)

2) If you already have the pdf file as an NSData object, you can save that to a file in your documents directory using

```
[NSData writeToFile:fileBPath atomically:YES];
```

3) On the other hand, if the PDF file is part of your application bundle (ie included with the app at compile time) it won't be in the documents directory.

Take a look at the documentation for [NSBundle mainBundle] -- that is where your PDF will be.

Comment: I am creating a pdf from UIView in my application & I want to save that created pdf file on iPad.

Comment: @Deepika I've updated my answer above.  You have a few different options depending on how/if you have created the pdf

Comment: Pdf is successfully created on iPad....but I am not able to find the icon of that file on ipad  so that I can read it directly.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not able to find the icon'?

Comment: I mean to say that how can I open that file outside the application ?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know that you will be able to open the pdf from outside of your application.  You *may* however be able to open the pdf with iBooks from within your app.  iBooks registers  itms-books: and itms-bookss: URL schemes so you *might* be able to open the pdf by constructing a URL with one of those schemas.

Comment: Here's another resource that may be helpful: UIDocumentInteractionController.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html