# Convert html file to Pdf file in iphone

Tags: html, objective-c, ios, ios5, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML to PDF conversion in iPhoneSDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930499/html-to-pdf-conversion-in-iphonesdk)

I have an HTML file in my app, but I want to convert it to a PDF file.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I searched a lot, but could not find anything helpful...

Comment: Here lies madness.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point read the documentation here [iOS Drawing and Printing Guide/Generate PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1)  You will find some sample code as well.