# Need help regarding printing UIView to paper printer

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, printing

i want to print `UITableView` and `UITextView` to the paper printer.. what is the procedure to do that using `UIPrintInteractionController`

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only print image or PDF type data using `UIPrintInteractionController`.

I guess you should draw PDF of your `UITableView` or `UITextView` separate and then can print out using `UIPrintInteractionController`. Use the following guide to generate PDF [Generating PDF Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1)

Comment: seems interesting, but what if i want to print the UI as is

Comment: This seems to be perfect in my particular scenario as i wanted to print and mail the content of the UI so, [Convert the UI to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454309/get-a-pdf-png-as-output-from-a-uiwebview-or-uiview) , Mail or Print