# UIImageView -> UIScrollview, crop and clip scroll view cooridantes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, crop

Can someone point me in the right direction. I've been searching around for this, but can't seem to find a clear answer. I have a UIScrollview thats 300x300 pixels. Inside that I have an  UIImageView. The idea is to allow a user to grab a photo from their library, then pinch and zoom it within the 300x300 scrollview. Then save the view port as a new photo.

So far I have this...

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    UIImageView *insideImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    scroller.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scroller.minimumZoomScale = 0.0;
    scroller.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scroller.delegate = self;
    [self setSendImage:insideImgView];
    [scroller addSubview:insideImgView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return sendImage;
}
```

This works fine. I can pull the image in and pinch and zoom. But now how do i get the zoom and coordinates to slice up the photo when the they are done?

Comment: Using your own gestures inside the image view would be better

Comment: Thanks, Otium. I think you might be right. Tried using gestures right on the UIImage view. Works great. Thanks.

Comment: So I've got the pinch/zoom directly on the UIImageView now. But I'm still not clear on how to save the current zoom/move state? Is there a "one shot" way with UIImageView? Or do I need get coordinates, zoom ratio..etc?

Comment: Capture a snapshot of the UIImageView using CoreGraphics

Comment: hi @MikeJaffe I need exactly same thing. How did you end up solving your problem?

Comment: I used this solution. Worked perfectly. http://codefuel.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/image-cropping-from-a-uiscrollview/

Answer (score 1):

Exporting a view's content into an image is pretty simple.

Try using the answer by St3fan in this post: [Get a PDF/PNG as output from a UIWebView or UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454309/get-a-pdf-png-as-output-from-a-uiwebview-or-uiview).