# Create pdf from Html

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I create pdf from html without taking screenshot or image of uiwebview in objective c in iphone app?

When I create pdf to capture screenshot of UIwebView, pdf resolution is not looking good.In zoom in or zoom-out pixel of its text distroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of taking it as a screen shot you can use quartz core to draw the UIwebview in PDF context. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566696/641062) is the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but pdf is looking blurry when I zoom-in or zoom-out it.

Comment: You will have draw your pdf again after zooming to get rid of the blurry effect.

Answer (score 3):

[Generate PDF from Html Page.](http://www.ioslearner.com/convert-html-uiwebview-pdf-iphone-ipad/)
I Hope this Will Help You.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have used this methodology but in this technique pdf is looking blurry when i zoom-in or zoom-out. If you have another technique please reply me.

Comment: @SauravSinha you might want to check my links plus the drawing with quartz 2d link like Vignesh said

Comment: Thanks Rohan for supporting me.

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Answer (score 2):

#### Load html in `UIWebView`

Use `UIPrintPageRenderer` from `UIWebView` Follow below steps :

#### Add `Category` of `UIPrintPageRenderer` for getting PDF Data

```
@interface UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF;
@end

@implementation UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
  NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.paperRect, nil );
  [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];
  CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
  }
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
  return pdfData;
}
@end
```

#### Add these define for A4 size

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)
```

#### Now in `UIWebView's` `webViewDidFinishLoad` `delegate` use `UIPrintPageRenderer` `property` of `UIWebView`.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)awebView
{
  if (awebView.isLoading)
    return;

  UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
  [render addPrintFormatter:awebView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
  //increase these values according to your requirement
  float topPadding = 10.0f;
  float bottomPadding = 10.0f;
  float leftPadding = 10.0f;
  float rightPadding = 10.0f;
  CGRect printableRect = CGRectMake(leftPadding,
                                  topPadding,
                                  kPaperSizeA4.width-leftPadding-rightPadding,
                                  kPaperSizeA4.height-topPadding-bottomPadding);
  CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height);
  [render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
  [render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];
  NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];
  if (pdfData) {
    [pdfData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tmp.pdf",NSTemporaryDirectory()] atomically: YES];
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"PDF couldnot be created");
  }
}
```

Comment: this is working for me too. But how did you define `CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)` ? I am using iPad Pro 9.7 and 12.9 so what will be the size for those ? any idea ? as this size cuts pdf into 2 pages even if there are lot space at bottom

Comment: its A4 size into pixel

Comment: and what about the DPI ?

Comment: I mean do we need to calculate pixels based on DPI ?

Answer (score 0):

[Get a PDF/PNG as output from a UIWebView or UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454309/get-a-pdf-png-as-output-from-a-uiwebview-or-uiview)

That is a good SO question that has the same approach..

however to create pdf programmatically, you can start here
Generate PDF on iPhone:

http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/02/13/Generate-PDF-on-iPhone.aspx

And:

Drawing With Quartz2d:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/drawingwithquartz2d.pdf