# Print the contents of a UIWebView to a .png

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Looking for an example to capture the contents of a UIWebView to a image file, all in the background.  Most likely the UIWebView will be hidden or framed off the main window so the user never sees this happening.

Thanks in advance!

Rob

Comment: This SO answer is exactly what you're looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2454622/953105

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a PDF/PNG as output from a UIWebView or UIView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454309/get-a-pdf-png-as-output-from-a-uiwebview-or-uiview)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will capture the content of the webview and that will be saved as a .png file

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview.bounds.size);
    [webview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Write image to PNG
    NSString  *pngPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: It's important to make sure the webView's scrollview doesn't clip to bounds if you want to capture the entire view