# How to rotate uiimage without stretchable in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios4

How to Rotate UIImage in objective C without stretchable and how to draw border for uiimage not uiimageview

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810966/ios-draw-nsstring-and-border-on-uiimage

Comment: Please search before posting...