# Add Multiple lines of text in UILabel

Tags: iphone

Any way to have multiple lines of text in `UILabel` like in the `UITextView`?

I dont wish to use more than 1 label in the view.

Comment: Please refer this [link][1] to customise the text in `UILabel`.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2210210/667586

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this code in your Program

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated iOS 6 onwards. Instead of using it you can use NSLineBreakByWordWrapping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done by setting the `numerOfLines` property to the number of lines you want to display. Or set it to `0` if you just want to be able to add as many lines as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-within-a-uilabel) which has everything you want

You can also set Properties like `numberoflines` and `linebreakMode`

have look to [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the `numberOfLines` property of UILabel and assign `0` for multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `lineBreakMode` and `numberOfLines` property of UILabel and set the frame as see the multiple lines.

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
yourLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,150);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,this is possible in .xib file select your label you found **Lines** option set value that you want to 
i.e.
   line 3

if you creating label  programmatic  than

```
 lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

CGRect currentFrame = myLabel.frame;
CGSize max = CGSizeMake(lbl.frame.size.width, 500);
CGSize expected = [myString sizeWithFont:lbl.font constrainedToSize:max lineBreakMode:lbl.lineBreakMode]; 
currentFrame.size.height = expected.height;
lbl.frame = currentFrame;
```